# Returning xml tag block via java method to xslt without using return type as Node

Tags: java, xml, xslt, cdata, xalan

I am calling java extension functions from xslt and using the return value of java function within xslt. The java extension function library does not have access to Transformer or translet reference used to transform input xml data via my xslt.

Everything was working fine until I had a requirement to return a complete xml tag block from the java extension function.

I returned the xml tag block as a String from java function but in the output xml it came within CDATA block. Now this CDATA block is not unmarshaled to the java object causing loss of information.

So, Is there a way to pass java.lang.String to XSLT as Node-Set OR any other work around/solution for my problem area.

Comment: If you had access to the transformer you could pass in a parameter using the `setParameter` method of the [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter) class.

Comment: `setParameter` thing is not applicable in this context because I had to pass some of the input xml's data as well to java extension function.

Comment: You could try to parse your XML string in your Java code into a W3C DOM `Node` and return that `Node`. Chances are that Xalan recognizes that tree model. Of course if you don't start with a string you should simply create a DOM `Document` and `Node`s using the DOM API.